# JavaScript Program Path Not Specified Error

Tags: javascript, webstorm, codepen

I've been creating a JavaScript game for a project recently and have done it completely on the CodePen website. I now am trying to transfer it to WebStorm to turn it into a basic website. However when I try to run my code I get the following error:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it, I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to get some help. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your run configuration look like? It appears you are trying to simple run a javascript file outside of a valid environment like node.js, or within a browser.

Comment: I think it's saying that it doesn't know which browser to open it in? I personally don't like using the IDE's debugging tools when writing javascript: it's just extra hassle that doesn't always play nice when developing on full stacks, I suggest just opening the .html file in a browser then refreshing the page (with a force reload like `ctrl + shift + r` in chrome to destroy any cached files) for changes made, and using the dev tools debugger

Comment: btw it's not recommended to add any project files to the .idea folder where the IDE stores project settings.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one, basically the error says, I don't know how to interpret this bit of code that you just gave me. You're missing local install of Node.js and NPM. Get the latest versions of these 2, and then go to File -> Settings -> Language&Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM and in the Node interpreter text box, point it to the path of where node.js was installed.

Answer (score 1):

You're running this JavaScript file with Node.js that is probably not installed on your machine. It seems that you want to run and debug your app in the browser instead. For that you need to create a JavaScript run/debug configuration instead as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

On a linux machnie,

- Install nodejs and npm

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nodejs
  sudo apt-get install npm
  ```
- Get the nodejs installation folder

  ```
  whereis nodejs
  ```

  Should print something like:

  ```
  /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/nodejs /usr/include/nodejs /usr/share/nodejs /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz
  ```
- Go to:

  ```
  Webstorm-> File -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node interpreter
  ```
- Copy paste the installation folder to the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS here. Solved the issue with:

```
$ brew install nodejs
```